# Is it possible to deploy SAPUI5 / OpenUi5 Apps in Web server other than ABAP AS?

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to deploy SAPUI5 / OpenUi5 Apps in Web server other than ABAP AS?

Comment: Is this a serious questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAPUI5/OpenUI5 is just an html5/javascript framework.

Of course you can use other types of web servers. 
As it states in the [OpenUI5 FAQ](http://openui5.org/faq.html):

> 2) Where can I deploy my OpenUI5 apps?
>
> In terms of a frontend toolkit, all you need to deploy and run OpenUI5 applications is a standard web server.